# Segmentation fault after value assignment to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

There is code:

```
void pop(int id, List *head) {
    List **previous = head;
    List **current = (*previous) -> next;

    if(head -> next == NULL && (*head).id == id) {
        free(head);
    } //if only 1 node in List

    while((**current).id != id) {
        *previous = head -> next;
        *current = previous;
    }

    (*previous) -> next = (*current) -> next;
    free(*current);
}
```

The program falls with `segmentation fault` on third stroke `List **current = (*previous) -> next` (I checked it with printfs).

CLion debuggers says `Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x113d349e2)`

If I do `printf("address = %d\n", &((*previous) -> next));` it gives me the address.

Comment: If your compiler doesn’t complain that you’re assigning a `List*` to `List**` then get a better compiler or turn the errors and warnings to the max. You can’t assign things that way. Also there’s no explanation what `next` is, for example, so there should be a [mcve]

Comment: next points on next node in linked list.

Comment: You should only have `List*`s there. Fix that and then try again.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for help. Now I understand what the problem. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void delete_worker_by_id(int id, List *head) {
    List **previous = &head;
    List *current = (*previous) -> next;

    if(head -> next == NULL && (*head).id == id) {
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
    } //if only 1 node in List

    while((*current).id != id) {
        *previous = current;
        current = current -> next;
    }

    if((*current).id == id) {
        (*previous) -> next = current -> next;
        current -> next = NULL;
        free(current);
        return;
    }
    puts("No worker with this id");
}
```